# How to work with long-running training jobs when working with Google Colab Pro+? Multiple limitations, Reliability issues

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, google-colaboratory, object-detection

I am working on finetuning some pruned models (eg. Faster RCNN) on the COCO dataset. I use MMDetection as a Detection Engine. My platform is Google Colab - I have got the Pro + subscription which gives me access to the top performing GPUs they have to offer on the platform. However, I have made the following observations which lead me to question whether this is the right platform for the job.

1. Since I am using Google Colab - my datasets are on the connected Google Drive. Google drive is unreliable when there are large number of files in a folder - as is the case with the COCO dataset. When fetching files from the COCO directory, it may unreliably return an Input / Output error and exit, but when retried again without any changes, it may just work.
2. Training for object detection for such large datasets can be time-consuming, but it seems that this Google Drive/ Google Colab connection is not meant for such purposes as I ran a training job which was expected to go on for 10+ hours, which ran for 6 hours without problems,then suddenly failed due to infrastructure issues and throwing an OSError like below:

[image is linked here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3Uul.png)

With the above context, my question is

1. if this setup is suitable for such long-running intense jobs, what can I do to ensure success in the face of such errors and issues
2. if this setup is not suitable for such work, please share alternative suggestions.